# Exception 401 with web service authentication

Tags: jakarta-ee, soap, weblogic, ws-security

This web service I run on WEBLOGIC server. Everything seems fine when I paste the URL WSDL to the browser, and the browser prompt to enter username, password. But in the client, when I invokes the service with the authentication same I did with the server, the server response with a 401 Exception.

This is my client code

```
SupplierService service = new SupplierService();
port = service.getSupplierPort();
Map<String, Object> rc = ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext();
rc.put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "username");
rc.put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "pass");

port.hello();
```

This is my web.xml configuration (the url wsdl is : localhost/shop/SupplierService?WSDL)

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Web service resources</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/SupplierService</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>

    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>suppliers</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-role>
    <role-name>suppliers</role-name>
</security-role>
```

This is my weblogic.xml

```
<wls:context-root>ass</wls:context-root>

<wls:security-role-assignment>
        <wls:role-name>suppliers</wls:role-name>
        <wls:principal-name>SupplierGroup</wls:principal-name>
</wls:security-role-assignment>
```

So is there anything I missing

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK 401 is for "The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized."

There are several things you need to verify.

1. Does the web service you are trying to access allow Anonymous Access? Authentication can be tricky for web-to-web calls
2. What is the web application running under, IWAM_xxx or IUSR_xxx? Or are you using an application pool running under a specific identity?
   3.SERVICE accounts can access your web service server.